# run a python script from local machine on the server after activating python3

Tags: python, linux, shell, server

i want to run a python script (which is present on the local machine) on the server inside a folder without copying it to the server. After login to the server i usually do two things to activate python3 as in the server default is python2(py3 is installed on server)

```
conda activate 
conda activate py3
cd folder_name
```

Additionally, the same python script need a data i.e. `data.txt` which is also present in the local machine.
However, i am trying something like this from local machine

```
conda activate
conda activate py3
cd folder_name
ssh user@192.168.1.101 "python ./script.py"
```

but it is not working.Any experts help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your local and remote setups are independent.

If you need to run your code remotely you need a python/conda remote installation. If you need the same functionalities, you can leverage on conda environment/vitual environment.

For instance, you can use conda environments as follows.

```sh
# local machine
conda env export > environment.yml
# copy environment to remote machine
scp environment.yml ssh user@192.168.1.101
```

```sh
# remote
## make sure you have installed anaconda, you can wget the installation file
## you don't need root permission, you can have a user-wide installation.

conda env create -f environment.yml
```

**EDIT**
If you want then to run with a one-liner command after activating the environment

```
ssh user@192.168.1.101 "conda activate <envname>; python ./script.py"
```

you are anyway better off with writing your command in a bash script (**on the remote**) that wraps all. E.g.

`wrapper.sh` example on the remote (remember to render it executable `chmod +x wrapper.sh`)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
conda activate <envname>
python ./script.py
```

which you run as

```sh
ssh user@192.168.1.101 "./wrapper.sh"
```

---

If you have set up your remote conda installation you can additionally leverage on piping to avoid copies

```sh
# wrapper.sh is local, but you need conda on the remote machine
ssh user@192.168.1.101 'bash -s' < wrapper.sh
```

Comment: already i installed py3 in remote server, i just need it to activate then run ssh command

Comment: see edit, you can use `;` to separate multiple commands in a single ssh call. better to wrap all in a bash script on the remote though

Comment: how to see wheather it is activating the envronment ot not

Comment: why don't you just ssh-in and you test your execution before a batched call?

Comment: try `ssh user@192.168.1.101`, now you have  a remote shell. There you can try your commands.

Comment: error is bash: ./wrap.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: does the wrapper.sh require to place in remote server

Comment: of course you need wrapper.sh on the remote, your local and remote execution are decoupled. Otherwise you can mount your local drive to the remote.

Comment: then script.py should be in local machine or remote server

Comment: you need a remote copy, to have an execution scheme as `ssh user@192.168.1.101 "conda activate <envname>; python ./script.py"`
use `scp` to copy

Comment: no no i donot want to copy the main script i.e. script.py to the server there people are copying my script

Comment: i just want to execute it from local machine

Comment: see up to date answer. the remote and local execution are docoupled. you need to deal with that, one way or another.

Comment: error is CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

Comment: plese tell me the better way @Acorbe

Comment: once more, just ssh in, and try to run directly on the remote machine: `ssh user@192.168.1.101`, then `conda init`